# Multi-select filter other than check boxes?

Tags: filter

I have 5 segments to choose from when browsing galleries. 
I want users to be able to browse more than one segment at a time.

The obvious choice is to have a filter under the nav with 5 check boxes.

What other UI options exist? Check boxes are ugly. I've tried a list in the sidebar and bolding the segments that are active but I don't find it to be apparent enough.

Comment: you could add one or more simple arrow shapes pointing to your selected sidebar list - much the same as ux stack exchange has an arrow  pointing to [ questions / tags / users / badges / unanswered ]

Answer (score 5):

I think [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) could be useful for you. You are interested in the second example on the page if I understood your requirements correctly.

Comment: I really like the last example on that page, good find.

Comment: I've seen this one. While it's great for a sub-nav filter, it doesn't fit well in a sidebar where a list fits best.

Comment: Great find! I was going to post a new question but this one fits the bill. Is there a way to customize it to fit only on one line?

Answer (score 3):

Another couple of options would be toggle buttons or flip switches. Here's a few examples:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand, maybe, you can need something like that ?

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/demos/simple-jquery-filtering-part2/

Comment: no because I need to select more than one category at the same time